# Unable to connect to atlas mongo db from strapi

Tags: node.js, mongodb, strapi, mongodb-atlas

I am using strapi and Mongo DB. 
Am able to connect to mlab Mongo DB, but not to atlas clustered Mongo DB.
I am using following configuration in strapi config :

```
{
    "defaultConnection": "default",
    {
      "connections": {  
        "default": {
          "connector": "strapi-mongoose",
            "settings": {
                "client": "mongo",
                "uri": "mongodb://<username>:<pwd>@mydb-shard-00-00-abcde.mongodb.net:27017,my-db-shard-00-01-abcde.mongodb.net:27017,mydb-shard-00-02-abcde.mongodb.net:27017/mydb?ssl=true&replicaSet=mydb-shard-0&authSource=admin",
             },
            "options": {"ssl":true}
          }
      }
 }
```

**Updated**
It is working as expected there was mismatch in the spelling of clusters. For one of the clusters there is capital letter.

Comment: Does your username or password contain symbols like / @ : ?

Comment: Yes but am escaping @ with %40

Answer (score 4):

If you just start with new project you just need to do run

> yarn create strapi-app my-strapi

then  Choose your installation type

> Custom (manual settings)Choose your installation type Custom (manual
>   settings)

```
 Choose your main database:
  SQLite
❯ Mongo
  MySQL
  Postgres

 Database name: (my-strapi) (shows project name by default; hit enter) 

Host: myproject-fcvyt.mongodb.net

 +srv connection: true

 Port (It will be ignored if you enable +srv): 27017 (do nothing, simply hit enter)
Username:<mongodb atlas cluster username> 
Password:<mongodb atlas cluster password> 
Authentication database (Maybe "admin" or blank): (leave blank hit enter)
Enable SSL connection: true
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB atlas uri should include `+srv`. E.g., `"mongodb+srv://<username>:<pwd>..."`

*this is assuming you are using the node.js driver and MongoDB 3.6. Full doc [here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/).

Comment: After appending +srv , throwing error as 
 "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid URI, cannot contain multiple hostnames"

Comment: Do you know which node driver you are using?

Answer (score 0):

for reference these are the options that worked for me

```
Choose your default database client mongo
? Database name: server
? Host: cluster0.qcyvc.mongodb.net
? +srv connection: true
? Port (It will be ignored if you enable +srv): 27017
? Username: petros
? Password: ********
? Authentication database (Maybe "admin" or blank): 
? Enable SSL connection: Yes
```